# setting datepicker input maxDate to now()

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i'm confused in setting input date using datepicker , i want to oblige user to choose date  less than now()
here the code :

```
        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="evenement">
                <div class='col-md-12'>
                    <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-lg" for="inputLarge">Date début</label>
                </div>
                <div class="init dateStEd">
                    <div class='col-md-8'>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class='input-group date datepicker start' data-dtp-end="#datetimepickerend">
                                <input type='text' class="form-control" id="datedebut" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

and then  jquery code :

```
  dateTimePicker: function () {
            $(function () {
                $('.datepicker, #element_ajoute').datetimepicker({
                    //sideBySide:true,
                    locale: "fr",
                    useCurrent: false,
                    format: "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm",
                    //format: "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm",
                    widgetPositioning: {
                        horizontal: 'right',
                        vertical: 'bottom'
                    }
                });
```

// on change of date , the calendar should disable all dates higher than today's date ( now())

```
         $(".datepicker.start").on("dp.change", function (e) {

                    $(this).closest(".dateStEd").find(".datepicker.end").data("DateTimePicker").maxDate($.now());// here the confusion 

          });
```

When i click on the calendar the dates higher than now() are not disabled , and i get this error :

> TypeError: maxDate() Could not parse date parameter: 1547629266259

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54213187/edit) then click the snippet editor `[<>]` and produce a [mcve] (And click TIDY before leaving the editor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$('.datepicker, #element_ajoute').datetimepicker({
            format : "DD/MM/YYYY",
            showClose : true,
            locale : 'it',
            showClear : true,
            ignoreReadonly : true,
            maxDate : 'now'
})
```

Comment: it works by adding ".start" to datepicker selector , thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.datepicker, #element_ajoute').datetimepicker({
            format : "DD/MM/YYYY",
            showClose : true,
            locale : 'it',
            showClear : true,
            ignoreReadonly : true,
            maxDate : new Date()
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See:  [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks.

Comment: it work as it's written on your comment , so by adding property  maxDate for the selector  $('.datepicker.start')  and  remove  the event " dp.change" function.!